# How to create a .deb file from installed package?

Tags: apt, dpkg

You can install a .deb package file onto a system by using `dpkg -i filename.deb`.

Is it possible to do the reverse? By reverse, I mean create a .deb package file from an installed package given a package name?

Comment: check this https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html

Comment: You should already have the .deb file in /var/cache/apt/archives

Comment: @DougSmythies My archives folder is empty :(

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Install dpkg-repack package:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
```

Example usage:- `dpkg-repack gparted`

replace gparted with your **package_name**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg-repack.1

Comment: an example would be great ;)

Comment: @postadelmanga if you wanted to repack an independently installed program you may run `sudo dpkg-repack vlc`
for say the vlc player.
however, i do not know about other packages with dependencies and everything else.

Comment: You can use `fakeroot -u dpkg-repack gparted` to run it without root privileges, if your user can read all files of the package you want to rebuild.