# Package mirroring

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Is it possible to copy a specific application that is installed in another machine to my machine. That means i want to install that same application in my machine. The .deb for the specific package is not available in other system?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to copy an application (or any other files) from one machine to another, but I presume this is not really what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve? Do the two machines run different version of Ubuntu? When you say the .deb is not available on one system, does that mean it is not available through any of the software repositories, or that you don't have an internet connection to download it?

Comment: These are same versions of ubuntu(12.04). and i have network access. in both pcs, but there is no .deb package on other machine's /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/592551/how-to-create-a-deb-file-from-installed-package

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `dpkg-repack` for this, which will put an already installed application back together into a .deb file, which you can then copy to the other computer and install there.

To install it, use

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
```

and to use it:

```
sudo dpkg-repack <packagename(s)>
```

Which will give you a .deb file (or multiple files, if you repacked multiple packages) in the current directory, which you can then install on another computer. Note that this will not back up any configuration or personal user data created by the application, you have to do that yourself.

**But:** It's probably better to find the original source of the software / package, such as an additional repository or PPA, instead of using this method.

Comment: The .deb file for specific package is created after the execution of repack command. But after trying to install it ends up with errors.

Comment: @JubinM What errors ?

Comment: I tried installing .deb with dpkg.  Tried installing the dependencies also but it's not working. The application is not showing up in dash.

Comment: What do you see when you launch the application from the terminal ? Maybe you need to logout / login again for the dash to pick it up. @JubinM

Comment: I tried logging out. Even while  typing the application name in terminal it's not showing up.