# How can I generate a .deb file for every installed package?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg

I used following commands to free disk space:

- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get remove`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- `sudo apt-get clean`

By doing so I also removed all the .deb cache files.

Is there any way to create `.deb` files of all the installed packages?

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me... Besides, 15.10 is outdated and no longer supported for almost 2 years. You should urgently upgrade your system to a supported release like 16.04 LTS or 17.04.

Comment: You could, but it would be a tremendous amount of completely unnecessary work. This is a case study in 'Why You Should Not Do Random Incantations'. You're fortunate that you didn't cause real damage.

Comment: @ByteCommander I did it just to free up disk space, and I didn't know that it will remove all the .deb cache files...

I know that I should upgrade my system and I also want the same, but the problem is I can't do it. I have a bunch of softwares installed in my system and I am afraid of loosing them while upgrading.

Comment: @RD017 that's the ONLY thing 'clean' does without further argument. There is no other possible use for it. It also erased all the hard work you just did with 'autoclean'.

Comment: The upgrader should tell you what packages are going to be removed, installed or upgraded. Anyway, if you can still download the .deb packages now (which is the only way to get them, you can't really build them from the files you have installed), you can also do that from an upgraded system, if necessary. Whether they will be compatible with another release than the one they're designed for is a different question, but unless you use very specialized software, I think the risk of losing any is quite low.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release for how to upgrade from an old, unsupported release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a deb file from installed package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592551/how-to-create-a-deb-file-from-installed-package)